# How to divide two cells based on match?

Tags: excel

In a `table 1`, I have,

```
+---+---+----+
|   | A | B  |
+---+---+----+
| 1 | A | 30 |
| 2 | B | 20 |
| 3 | C | 15 |
+---+---+----+
```

On `table 2`, I have

```
+---+---+---+----+
|   | A | B | C  |
+---+---+---+----+
| 1 | A | 2 | 15 |
| 2 | A | 5 |  6 |
| 3 | B | 4 |  5 |
+---+---+---+----+
```

I want the number in second column to divide the number in `table 1`, based on match, and the result in third column. 
The number present in the bracket is the result needed. What is the formula that I must apply in third column in `table 2`?

[image: Check the image]

Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by match? based on column name or based on cell value? when you write A - 2 does that mean cell $A$1 has value of 2? Or has the value "A - 2"?

Comment: Hi siggi_pop, thanks for connecting. I wanted to distinguish columns through "-"                        A B C are the entries in column A and the numbers are the entries in Column B. And the match is based on the alphabet.In sheet 2, for A, the factor is 2, so A in sheet 2 matches with A in sheet 1 and returns a value in third column, say 15 (30/2).

Comment: Ok so based on your answer 'I wanted to distinguish rows through "-"' would mean that A - 2 is same as $A$2 ( column A, row 2 ) correct ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `vlookup()` formula to go get the dividend. (assuming `table 1` is on `Sheet1` and `table 2` in `Sheet2` where we are doing this formula):

```
 =VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet1!A:B, 2, FALSE)/Sheet2!B1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention `table`, with structured references, though it seems you are not applying those here:

```
=VLOOKUP([@Column1],Table1[#All],2,0)/[@Column2]
```

[image]